# how to monitor if the connectivity between the rails apps and mysql database is established

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

How do we monitor that the connectivity between the rails app and the database is established. will rails try to re-connect the connection with mysql if it closes?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK yes, you could still check periodically a special controller you would create that displays whether the DB is up or down (using `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` for instance).

***Edit Tue Mar 30:***

I believe you could instead write a Metal and periodically check the result from it (using a rake task or whatever monitoring tool you're used to):

```
class ConnectivityChecker
  def self.call(env)
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
      [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, ["Connected."]]
    else
      # Leave it to Rails to deal with the request.
      [500, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, ['Database is not reachable.']]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i have written a ruby script which finds if the process is running or the mysql db connectivity is established and placed it in the scripts directory . can i call this ActiveRecord::Base.connected? from that ruby script?